# Cannot set Valid Audience in latest version of IdentityModel.Tokens

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory

I have updated System.IdentityModel.Tokens.jwt and it has warned me that the use of 'Audience' in the lower code block is obsolete.  I have done some research and can see the right way to set the audience moving forwards is:

```
var validationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
{
    ValidAudience = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:AudienceUri"]
};
```

> What I can't work out is how I join the two together?

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
{
     app.UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication( 
        new WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions 
         {
            Audience = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:AudienceUri"], 
            //TokenValidationParameters.validAudience = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:AudienceUri"],
            Tenant = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Tenant"] 
         }); 


    app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);
    app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions()
    {
    });
    app.UseWsFederationAuthentication(
    new WsFederationAuthenticationOptions
    {
        Wtrealm = realm,
        MetadataAddress = metadata
    });
}
```

}

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have tried this:

```
 TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidAudience = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Audience"]
                }
```

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else looking for a solution to this problem, here's how you use the TokenValidationParameters:

```
public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseWindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthentication(
                new WindowsAzureActiveDirectoryBearerAuthenticationOptions
                {
                    Tenant = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Tenant"],
                    TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                    {
                        ValidAudience = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings    ["ida:Audience"]
                    }
                });
        }
```

[Source](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-javascript-singlepageapp-dotnet-webapi/issues/9)